# Logarithm on the reals: negative power series?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I am well aware that $ln(x)$ has no Laurent series on the complex plane, because of its multi-valuedness, but I have always wondered whether a similar beast would exist if we restricted our attention to positive real numbers. Conversely, is it possible to prove that there do not exist real coefficients ${a_j}$, where j ranges over all the integers, such that for all positive real numbers x,

$ln(x)=$$\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}a_jx^{j}$ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there do not exist $a_j$ such that $\ln x=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_jx^j$ for $x>0$. Not even for $a<x<b$.

This is clear from a bit of basic complex analysis. If that series converges for $a<x<b$ then it represents a function analytic in the annulus $a<|z|<b$ in the complex plane, and there is no such function that agrees with $\ln x$ for $a<x<b$.